# ggplot2 Legend order - Multiple mappings?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am generating scatterplots with some acoustics data. I am finding the way the data is mapped in ggplot I am unable to reorder the legend in the traditional way with renaming the levels.

Here is the toy example for you:

```
tickpointer$stt
 [1] 0.000 0.166 0.324 0.515 0.734 0.909 1.059 1.191 1.319 1.445 1.561 1.683
tickpointer$highhz
 [1] 7338 7073 7312 7948 7975 7709 7895 7736 8293 8373 8081 9920
tickpointer$peakhz
 [1] 4969 4969 4969 4969 5250 5438 3938 4125 4594 4875 5531 7125
tickpointer$lowhz
 [1] 2351 2404 2510 2351 2802 2908 2882 3174 3598 4022 4580 5587
```

looking like: Highhz,peakhz,lowhz,stt in a dataframe

I plotted each of these in a ggplot:

```
require(ggplot2)

tickpointer

ggplot(tickpointer,aes(stt))+#fileoff is choosen as the x value to have a standardized starttime
          geom_line(aes(y=highhz,col="High"))+
          geom_point(aes(y=highhz,col="High"))+
          geom_line(aes(y=peakhz,col="Peak"))+
          geom_point(aes(y=peakhz,col="Peak"))+
          geom_line(aes(y=lowhz,col="Low"))+
          geom_point(aes(y=lowhz,col="Low"))
```

notice the legend is in the order: High, Peak, Low.
I would like it to be: High, Low, Peak.

Any leads or help trying to figure this out would be great. 
Cheers

Comment: This will be easier if you reshape your data to "long" format. For example: `library(tidyverse); tickpointer %>% gather(key, value, -stt) %>% mutate(key = factor(key, levels=c("Low", "Peak", "High"))) %>% ggplot(aes(x=stt, y=value, colour=key)) + geom_line() + geom_point()`. The `gather` step converts the data to long format. The `mutate` step is where we set the order of the legend levels.

Comment: I would recommend putting your data in long format (each row an observation), which will make any subsequent plotting much easier. Also, consider posting the example data frame with `dput(example_data)` instead of copy-pasting the print output.

Comment: Correction: Change the `mutate` code to the following: `mutate(key = factor(key, levels=c("lowhz", "peakhz", "highhz"), labels=c("Low", "Peak", "High")))`.